# Retrieving column names from table -Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table as below:

```
create table venue_ident

(venueid bigint identity(0, 1)NOT NULL,
 venuename varchar(100) default 'city',
 venuecity varchar(30),
 venuestate char(2),
 venueseats integer,
 primary key(venueid));
```

Whenever I use the query

```
 select DISTINCT c.column_name,
 a.attencodingtype,
 a.attnotnull,
 a.atttypid::regtype,
 a.attnum

FROM   pg_attribute a , information_schema.columns c ,PG_TABLE_DEF as p
where    attnum > 0
 AND    NOT attisdropped
 AND c.ordinal_position=a.attnum
 and c.column_name=a.attname
 and c.table_name='venue_ident'
 and a.attnotnull=p.notnull

ORDER by a.attnum;
```

It always outputs 6 columns instead of 5 . It shows primary key column (`venue_id`) twice with different values for not null condition.
How do i get just the 5 columns

```
(venueid, venuename, venuecity, venuestate, venueseats)
```

Comment: Just in case, add schema condition.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Tried adding schema condition,still the output is same

Comment: hi add some sample data..

Comment: For my application,i dont need to insert any values in the table.Just need to see the information of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pg_attribute table contains rows to represent primary keys etc. as well as columns. Since you've defined venueid as an IDENTITY column, there is an additional row for venueid that represents the identity property of the table.

You can see this by referencing pg_class in the query and looking at the value for relname:

```
    SELECT 
 c.column_name,
 a.attencodingtype,
 a.attnotnull,
 a.atttypid::regtype,
 a.attnum, 
 pc.relname
FROM   
    pg_attribute a 
    INNER JOIN information_schema.columns c ON c.ordinal_position=a.attnum  and c.column_name=a.attname
    INNER JOIN pg_class pc ON a.attrelid = pc.oid
where    
    a.attnum > 0
    AND NOT a.attisdropped
    and c.table_name='venue_ident'
ORDER by a.attnum;
```

For one of the "venueid" rows, you'll see relname is "venue_ident_pkey" instead of "venue_ident".

If you want only the column names of the table, then add an additional WHERE clause filter on `pc.relname='venue_ident'` (the table name).

Comment: @Arora - please mark this as the answer if it has answered your question - this helps other readers understand if the response is a good one or not. :)

Comment: AND pc.relname = c.table_name